# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token, Matching Game Assignment

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I am a beginner in JavaScript and I am currently working on an assignment where I need to create a game where you need to click on the extra face on the left side, using JavaScript. I keep getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here is my code:

```html
<html>
  <head>
   <style>
    img {
     position: absolute;
    }
    div {
     position: absolute;
     width: 500px;
     height: 500px;
    }
    #rightSide { 
     left: 500px; 
     border-left: 1px solid black;
    }
   </style>
  </head>
  <body onload = "generateFaces()">
   <h1>Matching Game</h1>
   <p>Click on the extra smiling face on the left.</p>
   <div id="leftSide"></div> 
   <div id="rightSide"></div>
   <script>
    var numberOfFaces = 5;
    var count = 0;
    var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
    var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");
    var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    function generateFaces() {
     while (count < numberOfFaces) {
      newImage = document.createElement("img");
      newImage.src = "smile.png";
      newImage.style.top = Math.random() * 400;
      newImage.style.left = Math.random() * 400;
      leftSide.appendChild(newImage);
      count++;
     }
     leftSideImages = leftSide.cloneNode(true);
     leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
     rightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);
    }
    theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = function nextLevel(event) {
             removeAllFaces();
             event.stopPropagation();
             numberOfFaces += 5;
             generateFaces();
             }
    theBody.onclick = function gameOver() {
         alert("Game Over!");
         theBody.onclick = null;
         theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = null;
         }
    function removeAllFaces(argument){
     while (theLeftSide.firstChild){
      theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.firstChild);
      }
     while (theRightSide.firstChild){
      theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.firstChild);
      }
    }
    
   </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What precisely is the error? What line does it occur on?

Comment: part 4.html:55 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
part 4.html:18 Uncaught ReferenceError: generateFaces is not defined
    at onload (part 4.html:18)

Comment: Don't use inline code there. Get rid of the `onload = "generateFaces()"`, and instead, put `document.onload = generateFaces` inside the script element. Iirc, you can't use code from within a script before that script element is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is some of the semicolons you're using aren't standard semicolons. If you test the character code of the semicolons you're using:

```
console.log(';'.charCodeAt(0))
```

You'll find that they have a character code of 894, meaning they aren't the standard type of semicolons, which have a character code of 59. Somehow, you've introduced stylized, non-standard semicolons into your code. This is clearer if you look at the picture below:

[Bad ";" semicolon Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffkuV.png)

Notice how the bottom semicolons look different than the top ones. Using these stylized semicolons causes the invalid token error that you're getting.

Go through your code and replace the non-standard semicolons with standard ones.

Comment: function removeAllFaces(argument){  while (theLeftSide.firstChild){ .. }

Comment: Just fix your semicolon of the lines

Comment: It's not legal semicolon . Try to remove two lines, and resolve "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

Comment: small semicolon and normal semicolon

Comment: You can't find that when you use stackoverflow editor. Put your code into JSFIDDLE editor and you can find it.

Comment: @Coder Now I see what you mean, you should have pointed that out earlier. It only appears to be that way in your picture though. You really should have been more clear about what you thought the problem was. Give me a sec to test. The semicolons look fine in his code though. They only look weird in your picture.

Comment: You're right. Do you mind if I edit your question to make the problem clearer? The way you have it worded is very vague and confusing.

Comment: @Coder I ended up changing a lot of your post. Sorry if it was too much.

Comment: @Carcigenicate sure

Comment: @Aktan Sorry, I meant "do you mind if I edit your answer". I was talking to Coder.

Comment: Thank you guys, you really helped me, I read every single one of your comments and even if it was not the solution you all took your time to helped me and in the end I reached a solution. Thank you!